# connection rejected from solr in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I use the sunspot-rails for search. These is a Rspec looks like:

```
describe "GET search" do
  before(:all) do
    system("rake", "sunspot:solr:start")
  end

  after(:all) do
    system("rake", "sunspot:solr:stop")
  end

  it "should do some search" do
    Text.search do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work. I got a failure:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
   Connection refused - connect(2)
```

But if I type `rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=test` by hand in command line, and then run the spec, it passes.

What's wrong? Isn't `rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=test` equivalent to `system("rake", "sunspot:solr:start")` in test mode?

(I tried `system("rake", "sunspot:solr:start RAILS_EVN=test"). Same.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `before(:all)` probably just isn't giving Solr enough time to start.

That said, you'll probably want to think hard about just what you're asking your specs to verify here. You can go a long way with mocking out calls to Solr with a library like Fakeweb.

Pivotal Labs also has a library called [sunspot_matchers](https://github.com/pivotal/sunspot_matchers) that can capture more fine-grained assertions about the searches you're invoking.

If you are going for real integration specs against Solr, I advise just keeping a test Solr running while you work. A tool like [Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html) can help manage your Solr proceses. I might use a `Procfile` like the following:

```
solr_dev:  rake sunspot:solr:run RAILS_ENV=development
solr_test: rake sunspot:solr:run RAILS_ENV=test
```

(Development is, of course, the default environment if no RAILS_ENV is otherwise provided to `foreman start`)

Finally, if you want to start Solr within your specs, you're already on the right track. Just toss a `sleep` in there with enough time to let Solr fully boot itself before your specs start running. Don't be surprised if that introduces a bit of unpredictable failure into your spec suite when the system is under load.

*[Edit: Quick and dirty `before :all` which uses `Sunspot.remove_all` to poll for availability.]*

```
before :all do
  `sunspot-solr start`
  begin
    Sunspot.remove_all!
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    sleep 1 && retry
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks. BTW, how can I know whether solr is running in my spec? I want a more proper custom exception instead of 'connection rejected'

Comment: I should think that `Errno::ECONNREFUSED` is pretty indicative. In fact, you could use that to poll for availability. Just hacked that out in an edit.

Answer (score 11):

The [sunspot_test gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/sunspot_test) will do this for you and supports RSpec.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild-ass guess, but I bet you have a Solr server configured in your **config/environments/development.rb** file to look locally on a given port, but no such configuration in your **config/environments/test.rb**

This is causing it to connect to the default address/port where you do not in fact have a Solr server running when you execute your tests.

I don't know enough about the Solr client in Ruby to be sure of this, but since no one else has weighed in yet I hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working just by adding

```
`rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=test`
```

to spec_helper.rb

Edit: I ended up going with https://github.com/collectiveidea/sunspot_test like Simmo mentioned.  It was re-running the rake task on every test run for some reason (even though I had it in the prefork block of spork).  Not sure why, but the sunspot_test gem seems like the way to go for now.