# Is there a way to disable (or automatically start/stop) sunspot when testing with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, rspec, sunspot

I came across this from an old fork of the sunspot gem:

https://github.com/pelle/sunspot_rails#testing-solr-integration-using-rspec

I liked how it could disable sunspot and then enable it in specs that need to test the sunspot indexing. I had tried those instructions and got `cannot load such file -- sunspot/spec/extension` before realizing those instructions were probably exclusive to that fork.

Currently before running specs I have to make sure to startup sunspot:

```
$ rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=test
$ rspec
```

What's the best way to handle sunspot within RSpec tests? How can I get it so that I don't have to manually run `$ rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=test`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7982262